# How to extract a portion of an XML tag value in a Bash script

Tags: bash, text-processing, regular-expression, xml

I have a XML file like this (`A.xml`) :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RunParameters xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RunParametersVersion>NextSeq_4_0_0</RunParametersVersion>
  <ReagentKitSerialWasEnteredInBaseSpace>false</ReagentKitSerialWasEnteredInBaseSpace>
  <ExperimentName>210913-RUN61-COCO</ExperimentName>
  <PurgeConsumables>false</PurgeConsumables>
  <MaxCyclesSupportedByReagentKit>92</MaxCyclesSupportedByReagentKit>
  <ModuleName />
  <ModuleVersion />
</RunParameters>
```

And I want to set a bash variable that contains the `RUN61` port of the XML tag `<ExperimentName>210913-RUN61-COCO</ExperimentName>`. The tag value always has the structure

```
irrelevant-relevant-irrelevant
```

separated by dashes.

I tried with `grep` but whitout any good result:

```
runNumber=$(grep -o '<ExperimentName>.*</ExperimentName>' | cut -d '-' -f2 A.xml)
```

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: usually, I'd ask what "whitout any good result" means, exactly. That is, what result you get instead, looking at that usually helps in figuring out what happens. But here, it's enough to look at the second part of the pipeline. What does `cut -d '-' -f2 A.xml` do?

Comment: How is the string inside the `<ExperimentName>` tags formatted. It it always `irrelevant-relevant-irrelevant`? Is `<ExperimentName>` always under `<RunParameters>`? Can there be more than one `<ExperimentName>`?

Comment: @AdminBee: With due respect, I don't see how `bash` tag is relevant to the question here. It is standard text processing stuff. If its a shell script, the tags should be `shell-script`. The question is basically shell agnostic

Comment: @AdminBee Yes, exactly . And always with the structure `XX-YY-ZZ`

Comment: @Inian The OP states that the operation is part of a shell script, so the (subordinate) task is to import the text processing result into a shell variable. Also, although not recommended, someone may want to add a solution that purely relies on shell text processing methods, so the shell syntax to adhere to may be (and you are right, only "may be", not "is absolutely") relevant. If you disagree, feel free to remove the tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are processing structured data, you should use a dedicated parser such as `xmlstarlet` to extract the tag value for feeding to `cut`:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "string(/RunParameters/ExperimentName)" A.xml | cut -d- -f 2
```

So, you can use

```bash
runNumber=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -c "string(/RunParameters/ExperimentName)" A.xml | cut -d- -f 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
experiment_name=$(
    xmlstarlet sel -t \
        -m '/RunParameters/ExperimentName' \
        -v 'substring-before(substring-after(., "-"), "-")' file.xml
)
```

This matches the node that we're interested in, and then strips out the middle part of that node's value using the two functions `substring-after()` and `subsring-before()`.

The output of `xmlstarlet` is then assigned to the variable `experiment_name`.

Alternatively, using `xq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

```bsh
experiment_name=$(
    xq -r '.RunParameters.ExperimentName | split("-")[1]' file.xml
)
```

This simply splits the node's value on the dashes and returns the second element in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -MXML -e 'for open-xml($*ARGFILES) {.elements(:TAG<ExperimentName>)>>.contents.put};' < input.xml
```

Sample Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RunParameters xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RunParametersVersion>NextSeq_4_0_0</RunParametersVersion>
  <ReagentKitSerialWasEnteredInBaseSpace>false</ReagentKitSerialWasEnteredInBaseSpace>
  <ExperimentName>210913-RUN61-COCO</ExperimentName>
  <PurgeConsumables>false</PurgeConsumables>
  <MaxCyclesSupportedByReagentKit>92</MaxCyclesSupportedByReagentKit>
  <ModuleName />
  <ModuleVersion />
</RunParameters>
```

Sample Output:

```
210913-RUN61-COCO
```

As others have mentioned, you will most certainly want to use a dedicated XML parser for this task. Briefly, for the above code Raku is called at the bash command line, and `-M` module `XML` is loaded with the command `-MXML`. Note the above code relies on `<` shell redirection [without redirection, you must stringify `open-xml()` input to `$*ARGFILES.Str` ]. The xml file is opened with `open-xml` and queried for desired `TAG`, `contents` are extracted and returned with `put`.

Actually, the OP provided perfectly good code using `cut` to extract the `RUN61` portion of the output, and the above Raku solution can be simply piped through the OP's code. However, for an all-Raku solution, simply interpose a call to `.split("-")[1]` between `.contains` and `.put` in the Raku code above:

```
raku -MXML -e 'for open-xml($*ARGFILES.Str) {.elements(:TAG<ExperimentName>)>>.contents.split("-")[1].put};'
```

https://github.com/raku-community-modules/XML
https://www.raku.org

Answer (score -1):

You can also extract that name by `grep` (option `-E` allows extended regular expressions):

```bsh
runNumber=$(grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+' A.xml | cut -d- -f2)
```

If you want to ensure the line of that tag, you can pre-filter it by another `grep` command:

```bsh
runNumber=$(
  grep '<ExperimentName>' A.xml \
  | grep -Eo '[[:alnum:]]+-[[:alnum:]]+' \
  | cut -d- -f2
)
```

**NOTE:**

Solutions based on XPath-expressions:

- are more readable
- might be much more fault tolerant
- **but** they can introduces some extra dependencies

Comment: -1 means "This answer is not useful".

Ok, thank you for the feedback from somebody. Why is this answer not useful? Can anyone explain? "-1" is just a number, a simple dislike without any useful details. I cannot learn from that.